# How to troubleshoot soldering issue?

Tags: arduino, motor, soldering, pcb-assembly

I have circuit working perfectly on a breadboard - motors are spinning as expected.
But same circuit with same components is not working when I soldered it - motors barely can spin (you hear buzz instead of spinning).

Spent few days trying to figure it out - checked all connections - looks fine.

What it can be? How to troubleshoot such situation?

p.s. Let me know if it worth recording a video of the behavior.
p.p.s. I'm a complete newbie in all that - so probably missing something obvious.

Breadboard connections:
[image: Breadboard connections]

Soldered board back side
[image]
*NOTE: Ground sometimes connected using very tiny wire*.

Soldered board connections
[image: Soldered board connections]

*Upd 6/24/2014: Inverted soldered board picture horizontally to match schematics.*

Comment: These questions are a lot easier follow with a circuit, and maybe you could flip the lower image to match the board or vice-versa? Having said that the ground on the Pro Mini looks like it might be going to the wrong spot but the above would make it easier to tell.

Comment: Peter has it, your ground is faulty. Check it carefully.

Comment: No it's not, theres a super tiny wire I didn't see the first time I checked.

Comment: "Ground sometimes connected using very tiny wire" - Why? You seem to have bigger wires. Supply/GND connection should be as low impedance as possible.

Comment: I did check ground. Re-soldered it with thick wires - no noticable effect. Will try to re-solder whole board with normal wires taking below suggestions into account...

Comment: Did carefully resoldered whole board. Most likely this is not a soldering, but something else...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your soldering job, some of the joints look messy and crowded. I would assume that since it's working on the breadboard, the problem is with the actual solder connections.

1. Use the continuity feature on your multimeter and see if any solder joints are touching other connections they're not suppose to.
2. Use flux before applying solder as it looks like your solder is not sticking properly to the metal. It works magic.
3. Make sure your iron is hot enough.
4. Make sure to apply the soldering iron to the component and not try to bring solder from the iron to the joint. This will cause a cold solder joint and that's kind of what some of those joints look like. Solder joints should look smooth and shiny.
5. Silly, but try jiggling the joints to see if there's a micro-fissure in any of the joints, which will cause intermittent connections.

I hope that helps you track down your issue!

Comment: Did most of it. Didn't help. This should be something else. Has something todo with current. When run on a breadboard current immediately goes up to 2A (stall current), on soldered board it's just 200mA (stall current).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to take an oscilloscope and look at the signals.  If you can't do this, I recommend building your next version sort of step-wise from the working breadboard version, testing as you go along.  First hard wire the motor connections, and jumper back to the breadboard.  Make sure everything works.  Then hard wire the DIP breakout, and jumper that back to the breadboard.  Retest.  Keep going until the breadboard is empty.

Also, just get in there with a multimeter and start checking continuity between points that shouldn't have any.  May have to remove you motor from the circuit first, as its low impedance and will confuse you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes (if the voltage level is 3v-5v) I'll use a led with soldered cables and use it to validate that ground and places that are supposed to have voltage are ok, I find this a little easier for a first validation, if something looks amiss then the multimeter, or the oscilloscope are the next step.